# Successful AJAX call on working PHP script returns nothing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm running a script which is supposed to send a user ID number to a database. The database grabs a bunch of image IDs from whichever row has the matching user ID, then goes to a different table and grabs the image URLs which match the image IDs. Then it returns the URLs.

The PHP script runs fine on its own, it returns the correct URL in either straight text or JSON, as requested.

As for the jQuery, the AJAX call does indeed get to the success function, because I can ask it to document.write something there and it will do it. When I ask it to print out the data, however, the AJAX call runs forever (I think it is repeatedly calling the success function? Based on the browser telling me that it is either waiting or transferring data repeatedly). Regardless, nothing is printed to the screen despite the repeating script.

Oh, also, no errors are returned to the console.

I am not sure why it is doing this and so here I am. I've browsed through the other posts here and randomly on the internet, with no luck. Any help is appreciated!

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
// define variables and set to empty values
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "Wolf*6262";
$dbname = "Game";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "GET") {
  $id = $_GET["id"];
}

$query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT imageids FROM users WHERE id = $id");

// Start user session
if ($imageIds = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {
    fetchUrls($imageIds, $conn);
} else {
    echo "Fail";
}

function fetchUrls($imageIds, $conn) {
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url FROM charimages WHERE id = '1'");
    $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
    $url = $array["url"];
    exit($url);
}

$conn->close();
```

The jQuery:

```
function getUrls (userId) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: {id:userId},
        URL: 'fetchChar.php',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        success: function (data) {
            document.write(data);
            document.write(userId);
        }
    });
}
```

Aaand here's where I define userId and call getUrls, it's in a separate HTML file:

```
var userId = <?php echo $_SESSION["id"]; ?>;
$(document).ready(getUrls(userId));
```

Comment: why `async:false` ? , have you tried to execute `fetchChar.php` on it's own to see if it's working correctly ?

Comment: I read somewhere that running the AJAX asynchronously might work. It doesn't affect the situation either way, apparently, because when I comment that out nothing changes.

And yeah, I've run fetchChar.php on its own, with the sole change being setting the variable $id = 1, as opposed to the script grabbing that variable from the AJAX call. So yeah it could perhaps be having trouble grabbing that variable in the first place. I've had trouble finding a way of checking that possibility.

Comment: well.. it can't call the success function repeatedly, you can try a couple of things, `echo $id` inside `if($_SERVER['REQ...`  to see if you're getting the content, and you can look into the browser's network to see what you're getting as a response,

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot and be back in a bit to tell you what happened. Thanks for helping out, it's very much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi to all. merry xmas

Comment: make sure that page hasn't error which may cause to stop resulting to empty content.

Comment: I think I was incorrectly returning, the echo statement fixed it. Thanks though, and happy holidays!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up doing the following, question solved:

Javascript file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   url: "fetchChar.php",
   data: {id:userId},
   success: function(data) {
    document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
   }
});
```

PHP file, near the end:

```
function fetchUrls($imageIds, $conn) {
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url FROM charimages WHERE id = 1");
    $array = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
    $url = $array['url'];
    $url = json_encode($url);
    echo $url;
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please modify your script: as standard way what prefer from jQuery: 
1. Change `URL` to `url`
2. Please avoid `async` defining
Like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    data:{ id: userId },
    url: 'fetchChar.php',
    // async: false,
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        //document.write(data);
        //document.write(userId);
    }

});
```

I added console log to show the return data, so that you can make sure that your data is returning correctly from `fetchChar.php` file using console log.